# Euler and Hamilton paths

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, hamiltonian-path, eulerian-path

[image]

So i was given this question. Here is my solution to this question.

This graph does not have a Euler circuit because in every iteration of the circuitry of the graph there is no possible way to achieve every line being crossed while starting and ending at the same location on the graph without the use of a single path multiple times. This was proven through trial and error and testing every iteration of the graph. What seems to be the actual issue is that we are always left with 1 path unused. It seems this is because of the formation of the graph geometrically does not allow us to create a circuit on this graph. Also because the Hamiltonian circuit is impossible on this graph it also infers that logically the Euler circuit also cannot exist.

Is this correct. I don't understand the Euler path part and how would you find a path.

Comment: Your argument for it not being Eulerian, even if it happens to be correct, would require showing *every possible path* which there are **far** too many to do by hand.  There is a *much* easier solution, involving looking at the degrees of vertices and whether they are even or odd.  Have you ever heard of such a property?

Comment: The question of whether or not this graph is Hamiltonian does not have anything to do with whether or not this graph is Eulerian.  There exist Eulerian graphs which are not Hamiltonian, just as there exist Hamiltonian graphs which are not Eulerian.  Eulerian requires each edge be visited exactly once.  Hamiltonian requires each vertex be visited exactly once.  The end result is that both an Eulerian *path* and a Hamiltonian *path* exist for this graph but neither an Eulerian *circuit* nor a Hamiltonian *circuit* exist.

Comment: @JMoravitz No can you lead me too it thanks

Comment: Think about the degrees of the vertices. An Euler Cycle would have to use one edge to "get to" the vertex, and another edge to "leave" the vertex. Since you are not supposed to repeat edges, these 2 edges have to be distinct. Can you see why the degree of every vertex therefore needs to be even, if the graph had an Euler-Cycle? Vertices b and c however both have degree 3, which makes an Euler-Cycle impossible.

Comment: And to continue that train of thought, since vertices $b$ and $c$ are what cause the graph to not have an eulerian cycle, if we were to remove the edge between them what would happen?  Can we find a cycle now?  Can we add back that edge?